# Will a longan tree on in a 40liter pot survive wet season outside?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care

I have a 4ft more tall longan tree inside 40 liter around 2ft top diameter pot. [image]  Is it gonna survive the wet season raining if I put it outdoors? Its been on a balcony with very little sunlight.  It has grown fine the last 5 months since it moved here. I want to know if moving it outside without shade with more sunlight will make it grow better or even fruit?

I can't just move it outside and move it inside again, since it’s big and quite a hassle so just want to know if I should just leave the tree where it is or should I consider moving it outside.

Comment: Where in the world is this longan tree?

Comment: Haha. Indonesia. Im in asian region. Not usa. So no snow here only dry and wet season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have adequate drainage at the bottom of the pot it should be fine outdoors.    Moving it to a place with more sunlight will definitely help it grow fruit - these plants want full sun, so it would surprise me if it fruited in its current location.

You will want to move it to an area protected from wind.

I expect it will be OK, but I hypothesize the plant may become stressed when you move it.   At minimum you will want to ensure it is well watered for the first few weeks after the move.

https://www.embracegardening.com/longan-plant-tree-care/ may be worth a read.

(Your USDA Hardiness Zone would be 13b (minimum temperature > 65f/18.3c)